# add n every x step repeat N times

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, numpy

after hours spent searching for a solution on SO I am here to ask for help.

I want to generate onsets where at each step I can add `n` at every `x` step and I want to repeat it `N` times, e.g: `A1 = 0`,  `A2 = A1+n`, and repeat this until `AN = AN-1 + n`.

I tried with `numpy.arrange` but it gives only a start and a stop there is no option to specify a repetition.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could you post an example of what you want?

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE] for what you tried; it gives us something to work with, and would help explain what sort of output you're expecting (and how it differs from what you got).

Answer (score 0):

I made a quick code.
N is the amount the code will count up to from 1.
x is the number of times you want to read the code before actually printing the line.
n is the number it increases by. (the loop's speed)

```
N = 10
n = 1
i = 1
x = 4
# Once i becomes 11 it leaves the loop.
while(i <= N):
    # prints the statement every x times.
    if (i % x) == 0:
        print("This runs every " + str(x) + " times.")
        print("Now printing: " + str(i))
    i += n
```

Output:

> This runs every 4 times.
>   Now printing: 0
>   This runs every 4 times.
>   Now printing: 4
>   This runs every 4 times.
>   Now printing: 8